# Can negative adsorption be considered equal to sorption?

Tags: surface-chemistry, adsorption

In my book it was written sorption is basically when the substance gets uniformly distributed into the bulk of the solid but at the same time its concentration is higher at the surface then in the bulk. for negative adsorption a same type of defination was there so is there any difference between them?

Comment: There is no difference, except that one is positive and the other negative.